# Add files to S3 Bucket using Shell Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, curl, sh

Goal: to push files in `gri/` to S3 bucket using `SendToS3.sh` shell script.

I am following this [Tutorial](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/aws/how-add-files-to-s3-bucket-using-shell-script.html).

`SendToS3.sh` is in cwd. It needs to fetch all files, that are not in sub-folders, in cwd's `gri/`.

**Terminal:**

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/data$ ./SendToS3.sh
./SendToS3.sh: line 17: logInfo: command not found
curl: Can't open '/gri/*'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
./SendToS3.sh: line 27: logInfo: command not found
```

**SendToS3.sh:**

```
bucket=simulation
files_location=/gri/  # !
now_time=$(date +"%H%M%S")
contentType="application/x-compressed-tar"
dateValue=`date -R`
# your key goes here..
s3Key=  # CENSORED
# your secrets goes here..
s3Secret=  # CENSORED

function pushToS3()
{
  files_path=$1
  for file in $files_path*
  do
    fname=$(basename $file)
    logInfo "Start sending $fname to S3"
    resource="/${bucket}/${now_date}/${fname}_${now_time}"
    stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
    signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
    curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
     -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
     -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
     -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
     -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
      https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${now_date}/${fname}_${now_time}
     logInfo "$fname has been sent to S3 successfully."
  done
}
pushToS3 $files_location
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: `/gri` also appears to be empty, so `/gri/*` is treated as a literal string, rather than an empty sequence of matching files. Use `shopt -s nullglob`.

Answer (score 0):

Your system doesn't have `loginfo`, so maybe switch that command to `echo`. For your curl error it could be a file permission errors, try running:
`chmod -rwx gri`.

Alternatively, you could use the [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead, which is much easier to use imo.

Comment: I'll look into AWS CLI instead, I may be a while before I report back.

Answer (score 0):

The error is at this following line. The folder `/gri/` is empty or the user launching the script cannot have access to it.

> curl: Can't open '/gri/*'!

Moreover, it seems that your server does not have the executable `LogInfo` installed, or it is not accessible from your script `SendToS3.sh`.
Verify the installation and add the binary to the `PATH` env variable.

> ./SendToS3.sh: line 17: logInfo: command not found

Bonus: instead of using `curl`, you can use `aws-cli` which is optimized to interract with aws components. Please find the documentation for `s3` here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

For example, you can copy a file to w bucket with this command:

```
aws s3 cp <path_to_file> s3://<bucket_name>/<path>/
```